# MODx выводит кракозябры вместо буквы "И"?

Tags: modx, utf-8, cp1251

Использую MODx REVO. Кодировка базы данных - utf-8,
сравнение - utf8_general_ci

в config.inc.php:
"charset=cp1251",

но, если я его меняю его на "charset=utf-8", сайт местами становится очередной кракозяброй Р“Р°Р»РёСЏ Р?РІР°РЅРѕРІР°.

Что делать то, кто подскажет?)

Answer (score 0):

> сайт местами становится очередной кракозяброй

Похоже на то, что у вас разные части сайта(чанки, шаблоны, контект и т.п.) имеют разные кодировки. В идеале конечно найти отличающиеся фрагменты и привести к общей кодировке(utf-8, cp1251 и т.д). Совсем в идеальном случае все же придерживаться рекомендаций MODX и использовать utf-8 в качестве кодировки и utf8_unicode_ci collation для базы данных(собственно, как вы и делаете).

Что может быть полезным здесь:

- https://docs.modx.com/current/en/getting-started/installation/standard#collations-and-charsets
- https://forums.modx.com/thread/104024/how-important-is-utf8-unicode-ci
- https://bobsguides.com/convert-db-utf8.html